# VBA Block Pivot Table Creation

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to write a sub that would disable the ability to insert a pivot table in a workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [protect the worksheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) without enabling the 'Use PivotTable reports' option. This will disable the Ribbon buttons related to Pivot as well.

If you prefer VBA, following code should do the trick.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If Target.VisibleFields.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Blocked creation of Pivot " & Target.Name & " on sheet " & Sh.Name
        Target.TableRange2.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack - but you can delete it *after* creation by using the following logic:

1. Trap the `Workbook_SheetChange` event and test if the `Target` range has a `PivotTable` property
2. If yes, get the `PivotTable`'s `TableRange2` and delete that `Range`

`Workbook_SheetChange` event code (in `ThisWorkbook`):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Target.PivotTable Is Nothing Then
        RemovePivotFromRange Target
    End If

End Sub
```

Code to delete range containing pivot (in a `Module`):

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemovePivotFromRange(rngTarget As Range)

    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim rngPivot As Range

    Set pvt = rngTarget.PivotTable
    Set rngPivot = pvt.TableRange2
    rngPivot.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If Removing the Pivot Insertion on Excel serves your purpose then try

File Menu>Options>Customize Rebbions> Expand Insert(Right Hand Side) >Select Tables and click on Remove button.

Please be noted that this will, remove the Table insertion option also:(